# How to check if all of the many fields are filled? [C++, VS 2015, Windows Form]

Tags: c++, forms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm making Windows Form project in C++ using Visual Studio 2015 and I have to check if all the TextBoxes are filled in and RadioButtons checked before I let the user go to the next panel. The problem is that when the "Next" button is clicked, I need to check all these fields one by one (textbox->text=="" etc.) and that makes really long "if".
Is there any other easier (or just better looking) way?

It might be stupid question, but I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0):

You can find many solution for this.

For example:
You can catch change in all the text boxes and use a numeric variable big enough to be used as bitmap with bit for each box, You start it when all bits are set. In the on_change, if the box is empty set the bit for the corresponding box, if not clear it. 
Now you can enable the next button only if the bitmap variable is zero.

Comment: Sounds good. I guess it might be better solution than mine. Thank you!